# SAPUI5 Wizard: View notification

Tags: sapui5

I'm dynamically loading views in wizard steps.

When i click on the button "Next" of the wizard, I want the view which is bounded to the completed step to be notify, so that a function of the view controller can be called.

please any idea of how its can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is the best way to do it, but that is how i solved it.

```
    var content = wizard.getProgressStep().mAggregations.content["0"].oController;
        content.onbeforeExit();
```

getController() could also work.
onBeforExit is the function i wanted to call.